# Error React Native IOS Exception '-[__NSDictionaryM length]: unrecognised selector sent to

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am new to IOS development and i have developed and build an app for IOS & Android in React Native and the app is fully working in Android. I have also installed the app on the iPhone simulator for testing, and after successfull build when the apps opens then it crashes and Xcode shows the stack of error.

Stack Trace

```js
2018-03-26 17:18:59.537548+0530 VwWoocommerceAppMain[57934:681649] -[__NSDictionaryM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000023abc0
2018-03-26 17:18:59.555 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.AsyncLocalStorageQueue] Exception '-[__NSDictionaryM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000023abc0' was thrown while invoking multiSet on target AsyncLocalStorage with params (
        (
                (
            cart,
                        {
            }
        )
    ),
    5873
)
callstack: (
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103f8212b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102874f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104003024 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
 3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103f04f78 ___forwarding___ + 1432
 4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103f04958 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
 5   VwWoocommerceAppMain                0x0000000101956824 -[RCTAsyncLocalStorage _writeEntry:changedManifest:] + 258
 6   VwWoocommerceAppMain                0x0000000101957104 -[RCTAsyncLocalStorage multiSet:callback:] + 436
 7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103f0636c __invoking___ + 140
 8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103f06240 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 320
 9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103f1ec26 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 54
 10  VwWoocommerceAppMain                0x0000000101966929 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 602
 11  VwWoocommerceAppMain                0x00000001019ac7a8 _ZN8facebook5reactL11invokeInnerEP9RCTBridgeP13RCTModuleDatajRKN5folly7dynamicE + 266
 12  VwWoocommerceAppMain                0x00000001019ac522 ___ZN8facebook5react15RCTNativeModule6invokeEjON5folly7dynamicEi_block_invoke + 78
 13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108bf32f7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
 14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108bf433d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
 15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108bfc855 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 1162
 16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108bfd1ea _dispatch_queue_invoke + 336
 17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108bf8f7c _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 733
 18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108c00102 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 772
 19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108bffda0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 132
 20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001091465a2 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
 21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010914607d start_wqthread + 13
)
2018-03-26 17:18:59.558030+0530 VwWoocommerceAppMain[57934:681649] Exception '-[__NSDictionaryM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000023abc0' was thrown while invoking multiSet on target AsyncLocalStorage with params (
        (
                (
            cart,
                        {
            }
        )
    ),
    5873
)
callstack: (
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103f8212b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102874f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104003024 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
 3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103f04f78 ___forwarding___ + 1432
 4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103f04958 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
 5   VwWoocommerceAppMain                0x0000000101956824 -[RCTAsyncLocalStorage _writeEntry:changedManifest:] + 258
 6   VwWoocommerceAppMain                0x0000000101957104 -[RCTAsyncLocalStorage multiSet:callback:] + 436
 7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103f0636c __invoking___ + 140
 8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103f06240 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 320
 9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103f1ec26 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 54
 10  VwWoocommerceAppMain                0x0000000101966929 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 602
 11  VwWoocommerceAppMain                0x00000001019ac7a8 _ZN8facebook5reactL11invokeInnerEP9RCTBridgeP13RCTModuleDatajRKN5folly7dynamicE + 266
 12  VwWoocommerceAppMain                0x00000001019ac522 ___ZN8facebook5react15RCTNativeModule6invokeEjON5folly7dynamicEi_block_invoke + 78
 13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108bf32f7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
 14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108bf433d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
 15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108bfc855 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 1162
 16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108bfd1ea _dispatch_queue_invoke + 336
 17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108bf8f7c _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 733
 18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108c00102 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 772
 19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108bffda0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 132
 20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001091465a2 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
 21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010914607d start_wqthread + 13
)
2018-03-26 17:18:59.561965+0530 VwWoocommerceAppMain[57934:681649] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Exception '-[__NSDictionaryM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000023abc0' was thrown while invoking multiSet on target AsyncLocalStorage with params (
        (
                (
            cart,
                        {
            }
        )
    ),
    5873
)
callstack: (
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103f8212b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102874f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104003024 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
 3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103f04f78 ___forwarding___ + 1432
 4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103f04958 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
 5   VwWoocommerceAppMain                0x0000000101956824 -[RCTAsyncLocalStorage _writeEntry:changedManifest:] + 258
 6   VwWoocommerceAppMain                0x0000000101957104 -[RCTAsyncLocalStorage multiSet:callback:] + 436
 7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103f0636c __invoking___ + 140
 8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103f06240 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 320
 9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103f1ec26 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 54
 10  VwWoocommerceAppMain                0x0000000101966929 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 602
 11  VwWoocommerceAppMain                0x00000001019ac7a8 _ZN8facebook5reactL11invokeInnerEP9RCTBridgeP13RCTModuleDatajRKN5folly7dynamicE + 266
 12  VwWoocommerceAppMain                0x00000001019ac522 ___ZN8facebook5react15RCTNativeModule6invokeEjON5folly7dynamicEi_block_invoke + 78
 13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108bf32f7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
 14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108bf433d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
 15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108bfc855 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 1162
 16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108bfd1ea _dispatch_queue_invoke + 336
 17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108bf8f7c _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 733
 18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108c00102 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 772
 19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108bffda0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 132
 20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001091465a2 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
 21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010914607d start_wqthread + 13
)', reason: 'Exception '-[__NSDictionaryM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instanc...'
*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103f8212b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102874f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
 2   VwWoocommerceAppMain                0x0000000101953a22 RCTFormatError + 0
 3   VwWoocommerceAppMain                0x00000001019ac9bc _ZN8facebook5reactL11invokeInnerEP9RCTBridgeP13RCTModuleDatajRKN5folly7dynamicE + 798
 4   VwWoocommerceAppMain                0x00000001019ac522 ___ZN8facebook5react15RCTNativeModule6invokeEjON5folly7dynamicEi_block_invoke + 78
 5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108bf32f7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
 6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108bf433d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
 7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108bfc855 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 1162
 8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108bfd1ea _dispatch_queue_invoke + 336
 9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108bf8f7c _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 733
 10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108c00102 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 772
 11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108bffda0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 132
 12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001091465a2 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
 13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010914607d start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

If anyone knows please help.

Comment: At some point you think that you are manipulating a NSString object (that's a guess) but it's in fact a NSDictionary object. Could you try to find the line causing the issue?

Comment: Seems like a `non object` item is being set in the `AsyncStorage`

Comment: @PritishVaidya i am seeting the asyncstorage like this   AsyncStorage.setItem("cart", {}); i don't why it shows error and its perfectly working in android.

Comment: @Larme i have changed nothing in the IOS files and the apps is fully working in android also i didn't how to get from where the error is coming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While saving data in `AsyncStorage` always use `JSON.stringify` irrespective of your what your data is:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('@key', 'will work on Android'))
AsyncStorage.setItem('@key', JSON.stringify('will work on both iOS and Android'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I've ran across the same issue.  The problem is that iOS is looking for a function named length() on the mutable dictionary, but NSDictionaryM uses count(). A work around is to stringify your object so it doesn't use a mutable dictionary.

The Android code works fine, the object is stored and there isn't a function pointer to the wrong function.

In my project I was trying to persist session keys using asyncstorage.  I had a wrapper called storage.  I'm new to react too, so I might not be doing best practices here.

```
import {storage, keys} from './storage';

storage.store(keys.session, res.data).then(()=>{}).catch(()=>{}); //Will crash in iOS, but work fine in Android
storage.store(keys.session, JSON.stringify(res.data)).then(()=>{}).catch(()=>{}); //Will work fine on both.
```

Here is the full method:

```
getSession(email, password){
    Network.login(email, password)
    .then((res) => {
        if(res.code == 1){
            storage.store(keys.session, JSON.stringify(res.data)).then(()=>{
                //Hurray
            }).catch((error)=>{
                throw new Error(error);
            });
            store.dispatch({
                type: actions.SESSION, 
                session: res.data
            });
            return res.data;
        }else{
            throw new Error(res.data);
        }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        this.setState({error: err.message});
    });
}
```

Comment: i have solved my issue by myself, have u created the asyncstorage.setItem("key", {}) async storage with empty object, if you have created then remove that.

Answer (score 1):

Please avoid an empty object in async storage in ios, that will resolve your issue

Answer (score 1):

For IOS you need to enter the empty object on the initailize.

Can use below code to solve:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('@key', JSON.stringify({}))
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was with MapboxGL `tileUrlTemplates` being an array with false inside.
The error message was much better when running on Android, just a tip.